# Google Maps - slowly moving map while gradually drawing predefined route

Tags: google-maps

I am looking for a script / tool which will allow me to define a route on Google Maps and then create a series of frames where the map slowly moves along at a given zoom level while drawing the (previously defined) route.

If it is hard to imagine think of a mini map/overview for a time-lapse/video of a drive in a car. The time-lapse/video shows you the view through the windshield and this minimap/overview shows you where the footage is taken on a map. This is actually what I'm going to use it for.

Does anyone know of such a tool or a better place to ask this question (if this is not a proper place)?

If it does not exist I will have to create it using the Google Maps API.

Comment: [animate marker along polyline](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_xml.html), [animate marker along polyline from the directions service](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. That's some really good starting points.